# how to logon to mysql as a non localhost user

Tags: mysql

I have two users set up, one is testuser@localhost and one is testuser@111.111.11.111 for example.  When I do the following command from ubuntu 20.04 prompt:
mysql -u testuser -p it prompts me for a password and logs me on to testuser@localhost.  If I try something like mysql -u 'testuser'@'111.111.11.111' -p it assumes it is localhost and gives an error message Access denied for user 'testuser@111.111.11.111'@'localhost'.  How do I specify and log on as a non localhost user?

I found the command, it is mysql -h 111.111.11.111 -u testuser -p.  For some reason I am not able to logon with the user with the ip address specified.  I keep getting a 2003 error which indicates some kind of configuration issue.  Can't connect to MySQL server on ' server ' (10061) indicates that the network connection has been refused.

Let me edit this to make more sense in what I am trying to do.  Eventually there will be two mysql servers, say one on ip address 111.111.11.111 and one on 111.111.11.112 for example.  I want to be able from a php script running on 111.1111.11.111 be able to access data from a table on 111.111.11.112 for example.  I am just now first trying to logon to the first server which is running a mysql database using the user name and ip address of the host.

Comment: ...what makes you think that you can "fake" the IP you are requesting the login from?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but [`-h` flag](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html) is to tell your mysql client which server to connect to that is hosting the database. There is no database running on `111.111.11.111` and so the connection fails. What you'll have to do is load up a mysql client on whatever system is running with ip `111.111.11.111` and attempt to connect as `testuser` to your mysql server running on whatever ip/hostname you are currently working on.

Comment: I'm just using the 111.111.11.111 as an example in place of the real ip address.  I will be using the real ip address in practice.

Comment: I have a mysql running on ip address 111.111.11.111 (as an example).  Eventually I will have two nodes, say 111.111.11.111 and 111.111.11.112 each running mysql.  I want to be able to initiate a connection from a php script on one to another.  Just as a first step I am now trying to login to the mysql running on 111.111.11.111 from a terminal prompt on the 111.1111.11.111 server.

Answer (score 1):

I will post the answer to the original question which is to include a host parameter in the logon command as follows:

mysql -h 111.111.11.111 -u testuser -p